# ORA-01855 different behaviour from fiddle

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g

Cutting to the chase:

This

```
SELECT to_date('2010-08-09 02:00:01 P.M.' , 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS AM') "date"
  FROM dual;
```

[Works in a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/33719) but yields `ORA-01855` on my DB. We are both running Oracle 11gR2. What should I be suspecting of and how to fix it?

Comment: Get rid of the dots in p.m.?

Comment: Have you actually *looked* at what you posted in the fiddle?  `to_date('2010-08-09 02:00:01 PM'`  works precisely because it's not what you've posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work in a fiddle or local oracle 11g

```
SELECT to_date('2010-08-09 02:00:01 P.M.' , 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS AM') "date"
  FROM dual;
```

This does in both..

```
SELECT to_date('2010-08-09 02:00:01 PM' , 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS AM') "date"
  FROM dual;
```

The p.m. is different.... are you sure you're doing the same thing in both?  SQL above shows dots fiddle doesnt..